# phantom stdout: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating)

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-crawler, phantomjs, nightmare

I use [nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) (phantomjs wrapper) to crawl webpage, but I get error:

> phantom stdout: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating
>   '$('a[href="/dien-thoai/apple-iphone-6-plus-64gb-ban-quoc-te--pid975.html"]').get(0).closest('section')')

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare'); 
var bandcamp = new Nightmare()
    .useragent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36")
    .goto('http://viettelstore.vn/danh-muc/dien-thoai-010001.html#SpecOrder=')
    .wait()
    .click('a[href="/apple-mid1.html"]')
    .wait()
    .screenshot('viettelstore.png')
    .evaluate(function () {
        var x = $('a[href="/dien-thoai/apple-iphone-6-plus-64gb-ban-quoc-te--pid975.html"]').get(0).closest('section')
        var y = $(x).find('.b-price.b-price_size3').find('.b-price__num').text()
        return {name: y};
    },function (value) {console.log(value.name);})
    .run(function (err, nightmare) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('Done!');
    });
```

The page screenshort after clicking is right as expected. The jquery code run ok when testing in console of browser. So I think the problem come from phantomjs